# Convergence of sequences in cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ be an arbitrary set. The non-empty open nsets are the complements offinite sets. We have to define also the empty set.

A sequence $x_n \to x$ converges as for the cofinite topology iff for each open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, $U = X \setminus \{s\}$ for a $s$ with $x \neq s$, it holds that almost all $x_n$ are in $U$. So if $x \neq s$, thenalmost all $x_n \neq s$. If infinitelymany $x_n=s$ then $x=s$.

Have I understood that correctly?

So considering the case $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$:

Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $0$. Since $\Bbb R\setminus U$ must be finite, $U$ containsallbut a fininte numberof terms of the sequence. Therefore $x_n\rightarrow 0$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Generally, convergence in non Hausdorff spaces don't behave well, because by this definition $x_n\to0$ but also $x_n\to y$ for any $y\in\mathbb R$

Comment: Thank you!! :-) @MatíasUres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your characterization of convergence is not complete.  A sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent in this topology iff no point $s$ is repeated infinitely many times in the sequence. In this case the sequence converges to every point of the space.

In particular, a sequence of distinct points like $(\frac 1 n )$ converges to every point.

Comment: That means since for every $n$ weget a different result the sequence converges to every point?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, the sequence contains infinitely many different points and so it converges everywhere.

Comment: Ok! Could you give me an example that doesnot converge in this topology? To understand that better! @HennoBrandsma

Comment: @MaryStar $0,1,0,1,0,1,\ldots$ does not converge anywhere, e.g.

Comment: This is because $0$ and $1$ are repeated infinitly many times. So also $x_n=(-1)^n$ doesn't converge, but $x_n=n$ converges, right? @HennoBrandsma

Comment: @MaryStar You are right.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :-)